# What is Usage of TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE while creating Statement object

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection, resultset

JavaDoc says: "The constant indicating the type for a ResultSet object that is scrollable but generally not sensitive to changes to the data that underlies the ResultSet"
.

I am clear about the scrollable part  but have doubts regarding the latter part of statement.
I am using following code snippet for validate my understanding.

```
        conn = getConnection();
        Statement stmt = conn
                .createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                        ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        String query = "select * from vehicle";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        rs.absolute(2);
        System.out.print(rs.getString(2));
        System.out.println("Waiting........");
        Thread.sleep(20000); //1 manually changed database entry
        rs.refreshRow();
        System.out.println(rs.getString(2));//2 Surprisingly changes is reflected
```

At Comment 1, I did manual changes in the database then I called rs.refreshRow() method. After this At Comment 2, when when I accessed the value of second column then surprisingly change in value of second column is reflected. As per my understanding this change should not be reflected, as 'it is insensitive to changes done by other'(as per JavaDoc). Can anybody explain me what is its actual usage?

Comment: Have you checked that it is actually insensitive? If a driver cannot support insensitive, it is allowed to upgrade to sensitive.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel How to check it whether it is actually insensitive? BTW I am using MySQL JDBC Driver

Comment: [`Statement.getResultSetType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSetType--) and/or [`ResultSet.getType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getType--)

Comment: its returning 1004 which means driver is supporting insensitive.

Comment: I don't use MySQL, but it is entirely possible that the driver doesn't (or can't) entirely honor the requirements of insensitive, reasons could be anything from bugs, misinterpretation of the spec, use of MyISAM (which doesn't have transactionality!), etc.

Answer (score 1):

I investigated this a while ago, specifically with regard to MySQL Connector/J. As far as I could tell, the settings `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` and `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` did not actually affect the behaviour when retrieving data from MySQL.

Several similar questions and blog posts I found referred to the MySQL Connector/J documentation, where in the section on [JDBC API Implementation Notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) it says that

> By default, ResultSets are completely retrieved and stored in memory. In most cases this is the most efficient way to operate and, due to the design of the MySQL network protocol, is easier to implement.

It goes on to talk about using `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, `ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY`, and `stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);` as "a signal to the driver to stream result sets row-by-row", but even in that case my testing showed that the entire ResultSet was still being retrieved as soon as I did `stmt.executeQuery(...)`. (Although perhaps I missed some other connection setting that wasn't explicitly mentioned in that section of the MySQL Connector/J documentation.)

Finally I came to the conclusion that the `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_[IN]SENSITIVE` setting really doesn't make any difference under MySQL Connector/J. While simply scrolling around the ResultSet it always seems to act like it is `INSENSITIVE` (ignoring any changes to existing rows that were made by other processes), but `rs.refreshRow();` always returns the latest data (including changes made by other processes) as though it is `SENSITIVE` even if the ResultSet is supposed to be `INSENSITIVE`.

Comment: For TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE I changes resultSet object using rs.upateXXX() but changes are not reflected when I again access using rs.getXXX().

Comment: Do you call `rs.updateRow()` after `rs.upateXXX()`? Also does the behaviour change if you use `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` instead of `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`?

Comment: No I haven't called rs.updatRow() because I was trying to  track rs object. No behaviour doesn't changed after changing from INSENSITIVE to SENSITIVE. It remains same